# How can I access pivot table attributes in doctrine without having entity for it

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have a many to many relationship between Location and Areas. So there are three tables location, areas and location_area(the pivot table). Now as we know on the pivot table I only have foreign keys from both table. So doctrine won't allow an entity for it as it requires primary key for an entity and logically the two foreign keys form a surrogate key. I don't want to add an extra column id to the table.

I have areas many to many relationship on the location table. So this is the query that I have wrote.

```
$query->leftJoin('q.areas', 'a');
```

And I need the location_areas table attribute for some condition. when I tried to access its attribute via the join that I have made above. Since it is a join with the many to many relationship areas so I assume it should return the pivot table attributes as well but it never does, What should I do in this situation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You create yourself a LocationArea entity and then setup one to many relations with area and location.

Comment: @Cerad i mentioned symfony won't allow me to create entity for pivot table unless i add extra column id as primary key

Comment: Actually it will.  Doctrine (not Symfony) does support composite keys.  I don't have an example handy but their are plenty out there.  The thing is, once you start adding attributes to LocationArea you may as well add a primary key just to keep things simple.  And in case it is not obvious, you do not use the many to many relation in this scenario.